# MATLAB plot failing due to Index exceeding matrix dimensions

Tags: matlab

I was wondering if someone could point out why I keep failing Test 1 and 2 despite my plot appearing as it should be. 
My goal is to plot a bacteria population using three different K values on the same plot however I am failing due to the Index Exceeding Matrix Dimensions.
I am unsure what this means and how it relates to the plot.

I appreciate any help.

Thank you.

```
`function [bacteria_plot] = BacteriaPop(K,BacteriaPop)
C = 100; 
r = 1; 
t = 0:20; 
K = 1000;
Kk = 3000;
kK = 5000;
BacteriaPop = (C.*exp(r.*t))./(1+(C./K).*exp(r.*t));
BacteriaPop = (C.*exp(r.*t))./(1+(C./Kk).*exp(r.*t));
BacteriaPop = (C.*exp(r.*t))./(1+(C./kK).*exp(r.*t));
hold on
plot(t,BacteriaPop)
```

end
`
[![Code, Plot and Error][2]][2]

Comment: You have a function and a variable of the same name. Rename one of them. Also, fix every one of the lint warnings you get from the editor (code with red wriggly lines under it).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I followed your advice and my code passed the other two tests. Its still not perfect but I have a better idea of how it went wrong thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some help I have changed my code to

```
function [bacteria_plot] = bacteria_growth(K,Kk,kK,Y)
C = 100; 
r = 1; 
t = 0:20; 
K = 1000;
Kk = 3000;
kK = 5000;
y(:,1) = (C.*exp(r.*t))./(1+(C./K).*exp(r.*t));
y(:,2) = (C.*exp(r.*t))./(1+(C./Kk).*exp(r.*t));
y(:,3) = (C.*exp(r.*t))./(1+(C./kK).*exp(r.*t));
hold on
plot(t,y)
hold off
```

end

It is still not perfect but it passed all the tests. 
Any constructive criticism to streamline this code will be welcomed.